# How to change auto-complete search mechanism C#

Tags: c#, api, autosuggest

I am writing WinForm project on C#. I need to use autocompete suggest based on variations of Regular Expressions search mode in different situations. The built-in autocomplete suggest mode from CustomSource use search mechanism on beginning of string only. How can I change the search mode based on Regular Expression search mode? If it's impossible. How can I create or implement the Auto-Suggest Form class used by C# and Windows from win API? I need exactly this form class.
Thank's, Kirill.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good looking tutorial : [Create An AutoComplete TextBox Control In C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c#/) at http://www.dreamincode.net, and the fill source code is download about at the bottom.

You should be able to change OnTextChanged to use you regex to do the lookup.